Which is correct "… than what you have" or "… than you have."?
I am looking at sentences containing "than" and "than what":


I have more chocolate than you have
I have more chocolate than what you have


Which is more correct?

Essentially, both are correct. However, the second one isn't the most normal or fluent way to express the meaning. "what" is somewhat redundant in this case, since you're just trying to compare the number of chocolates. The first sentence is fluent enough. As a side note, here's another fluent way to say this:

I have more chocolate than you.

(no need for "have"; it's also a bit redundant)
